# SDAVExportSession quality-based compression

Tags: compression, avassetwriter, avassetexportsession

I am compressing a video for upload using [`SDAVAssetExportSession`](https://github.com/rs/SDAVAssetExportSession/) (drop-in replacement for `AVAssetExportSession` built on top of `AVAssetWriter`):

```
SDAVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[SDAVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:composition];

exportSession.videoSettings =
@{
  AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecH264,
  AVVideoWidthKey: @640,
  AVVideoHeightKey: @640,
  AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: @
      {
      AVVideoAverageBitRateKey: @1100000,
      AVVideoProfileLevelKey: AVVideoProfileLevelH264High40,
      },
  };
```

When encoding video using [Handbrake](https://handbrake.fr/) on OSX I can choose to use a "Constant Quality" setting instead of average bitrate:

[image]

This seems to give better results on a variety of video sources.

Can I do the same with `SDAVAssetExportSession`?

If not, is there another way I could compress the video using "Constant Quality" compression?